# Passing multiple values to a stored procedure from a dropdown listitem value

Tags: sql, visual-studio, gridview, parameter-passing

I have a column in my table that contains values S, A, P and N.

I have a grid that is updated by a dropdown list.

The grid is attached to a stored procedure.

From the dropdown list I have the following options which I would like to pass the appropriate value to the stored procedure.

- SEN - which should pass S, A and P
- Non-SEN - which should pass only N

How do I pass multiple values for SEN, so that the results are filtered down to any record that is either S, A or P? 'N' can be passed as the listitem value, but I'm not sure how to pass all 3 in the case of SEN. Can it be achieved using the value property of the dropdown listitem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can pass comma separated values to stored procedure.

There are 2 ways to process this comma separated list in stored procedure

1. Relatively easy way to use dynamic sql and use In operator
2. Another way is to split string into table and use in clause

Here is an example of second type

I am creating a function that will return table type

CREATE Function [dbo].[Splitter] (@CommaSperatedString varchar(max))
Returns @Tbl_Values Table  (indValues varchar(500))  As

Begin 
IF(@CommaSperatedString != '') 
    Begin
         Set @CommaSperatedString =  @CommaSperatedString + ',' 
         -- Indexes to keep the position of searching
         Declare @Pos1 Int
         Declare @pos2 Int

```
     -- Start from first character 
     Set @Pos1=1
     Set @Pos2=1

     While @Pos1<Len(@CommaSperatedString)
     Begin
      Set @Pos1 = CharIndex(',',@CommaSperatedString,@Pos1)
      Insert @Tbl_Values Select  Cast(Substring(@CommaSperatedString,@Pos2,@Pos1-@Pos2) As varchar(500))
      -- Go to next non comma character
      Set @Pos2=@Pos1+1
      -- Search from the next charcater
      Set @Pos1 = @Pos1+1
     End 
End
```

Else
    Begin
        Insert @Tbl_Values values (1)
    End
Return
End

And use this in your procedure like this

select * from Table
     where values in (select * from Splitter(@CommaList))

This will solve your problem.

Comment: thanks for this. In the end I resolved it by using a case statement in the WHERE clause of my stored procedure. However, both of your suggestions are resolves using the SQL too which pointed me in the right direction.